# Fastest solution to list all pairs of n integers?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, combinations, combinatorics

I want to list all possible pairs of the integers `[1, n]` with a large `n`. I find myself looking for the fastest option. This is what I've come up with so far.

Matlab's [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) and [`combnk`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/combnk.html?searchHighlight=combnk) methods recommend `n<15` for listing all possible combinations because of the explosive number of combinations. So how fast this is depends on the n.

```
pair = nchoosek(1:n, 2);
```

Another option would be to use a nested for loop

```
kk =1;
pair = zeros(nchoosek(n, 2), 2);
for ii = 1:n
    for jj = ii+1:n
        pair(kk, :) = [ii, jj];
        kk = kk + 1;
    end
end
```

This would be relatively slow.

I also thought of using the `ind2sub` function directly

```
pair_adjacency = tril(ones(n),  -1);
[x, y] = ind2sub(size(pair_adjacency), find(pair_adjacency==1)); 
pair = [x, y];
```

Timing these methods in a loop, 10 times each with `n=1000`, I get fastest to slowest

1. ind2sub (0.15 sec)
2. for loop (16.3 sec)
3. nchoosek (16.8 sec)

It seems like `ind2sub` is the fastest way to go by a long shot. Just out of curiosity, what are other options that may or may not be faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To replace `nchoosek(1:N,2)`**

With `bsxfun` -

```
[Y,X] = find(bsxfun(@gt,[1:N]',[1:N]))
pair = [X, Y];
```

With `tril` and `find` only (without `ind2sub`) -

```
[y,x] = find(tril(true(N),-1))
pair = [X, Y];
```

Comment: The very versatile `bsxfun` again!

Comment: Speedy! I clock both at about 0.08 sec using the same setup as before.

Comment: @2cents Awesomeness! very kool indeed.

Comment: @Benoit_11 I got a mind-reading keyboard from future! ;) Actually I stumbled upon this problem few days ago! No magic really :)

Comment: Great job :) I especially like the trick with the `tril` matrix that's very clever.