# Efficient way to generate all possible combinations of elements in 2 arrays

Tags: algorithm, matlab, combinations, permutation

I have an array A=[1,2] and B=[5,6]
I want to generate an array C=[1*1,2*2,5*5,6*6,1*2,1*5,1*6,2*5,2*6,5*6]
That is all the possible combinations (a*b is equal to b*a and hence only 1 of them should be on the resultant C array).

Does matlab have an inbuilt function I can use to achieve this?
Can you help me?

Comment: What if you have A=[2,4] B=[3,6] - should 12 appear twice (3*4,6*2) or only once?

Comment: How does *2 arrays* come into play here? It seems it doesn't matter which elements are in which array. It should be the same as choosing 2 elements from `[A,B]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) could be suggested here.

**Approach #1**

```
%// Form a concatenated array
AB = [A(:) ; B(:)]

%// Get pairwise multiplications between all elements
allvals = bsxfun(@times,AB,AB.') %//'

%// Discard the repeated ones for the final output
C = allvals(bsxfun(@le,[1:numel(AB)]',1:numel(AB)))
```

**Approach #2**

```
%// Form a concatenated array
AB = [A(:) ; B(:)]

%// Get "non-repeated" pairwise indices
[Y,X] = find(bsxfun(@le,[1:numel(AB)]',1:numel(AB))) %//'

%// Elementwise multiplications across all such pairs for final output
C = AB(X).*AB(Y)
```

The second one is based on [`Fastest solution to list all pairs of n integers`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28506266/3293881) and is less memory hungry than the first approach.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use [`pdist`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) (from the Statistics Toolbox) with an anonymous function:

```
AB = [A(:); B(:)];
C = [AB.'.^2 pdist(AB, @(x,y) x*y)];
```

Comment: Good thinking on this! Did some quick tests and this one is the fastest for really large arrays!

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! In recent versions of Matlab `pdist` uses a mex file to do the actual computations; that must be (part of) the reason

Comment: Well, my tests state that my Approach #1 `bsxfun` performs really well until numel(A) is `2000` i.e. numel(AB) is `4000`, after which I am guessing the heavy memory requirements of `bsxfun` kicks in and then `pdist` starts to shine thereafter. Not seeing a clear winner!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
%merge
AB = [A(:) ; B(:)]
%multiply to get all combinations
C=AB*AB'
%delete everything below the first diagonal
C=C(triu(true(numel(AB))));
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't add much to the question that you are using two vectors. You just want the product of every `n choose 2` combination of the concatenation `x = [A(:); B(:)]`.

```
prod(x(nchoosek(1:numel(x), 2)), 2)
```